# Java Wicket resource issue

Tags: java, wicket, resourcereference

Im working on a web app where we keep the code and web resources (such as css, image files etc) separated.

I have a file located here:

project root/src/main/webapp/images/icons/16/add.png

And in this location:

project root/src/main/java/se/su/dsv/scipro/icons

I have a class like so:

```
package se.su.dsv.scipro.icons;

import org.apache.wicket.ResourceReference;
import org.apache.wicket.behavior.AttributeAppender;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.image.Image;
import org.apache.wicket.model.Model;


public class ImageIcon extends Image {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static final String ICON_NEW_ADD = "../../../../../../webapp/images/icons/16/add.png";

    public ImageIcon(String id, String name, String size, String alt){
        super(id, new ResourceReference(ImageIcon.class, name));
        if(alt != null){
            add(new AttributeAppender("alt", true, new Model<String>(alt), " "));
        }
        else {
            add(new AttributeAppender("alt", true, new Model<String>(name), " "));
        }
    }

    public ImageIcon(String id, String name){
        this(id, name, "", null);
    }

    public ImageIcon(String id, String name, String alt){
        this(id, name, "", alt);
    }

    public static ResourceReference getImage(String imageName, String imageSize){
        return new ResourceReference(ImageIcon.class, imageName);
    }
}
```

But when I use this class somewhere in a panel or a page, e.g. like this:

```
add(new ImageIcon("new_add", ImageIcon.ICON_NEW_ADD));
```

I get the following exception:

```
2011 Oct 18 11:11:17,947[ERROR] - RequestCycle - Can't instantiate page using constructor public se.su.dsv.scipro.basepages.DemoPage(org.apache.wicket.PageParameters) and argument 
org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Can't instantiate page using constructor public se.su.dsv.scipro.basepages.DemoPage(org.apache.wicket.PageParameters) and argument 
    at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.createPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:212)
    at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:65)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.newPage(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:298)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.getPage(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:320)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.processEvents(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:234)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.processEvents(AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.java:92)
        at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.processEventsAndRespond(RequestCycle.java:1250)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.step(RequestCycle.java:1329)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.steps(RequestCycle.java:1436)
    at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.request(RequestCycle.java:545)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doGet(WicketFilter.java:486)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:319)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:113)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.createPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:188)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid path ../../../../../../webapp/images/icons/16/add.png
    at org.apache.wicket.util.lang.Packages.absolutePath(Packages.java:105)
    at org.apache.wicket.util.lang.Packages.absolutePath(Packages.java:44)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.PackageResource.<init>(PackageResource.java:504)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.PackageResource.newPackageResource(PackageResource.java:448)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.PackageResource.get(PackageResource.java:424)
    at org.apache.wicket.ResourceReference.newResource(ResourceReference.java:304)
    at org.apache.wicket.ResourceReference.bind(ResourceReference.java:151)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.image.resource.LocalizedImageResource.bind(LocalizedImageResource.java:180)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.image.resource.LocalizedImageResource.setResourceReference(LocalizedImageResource.java:246)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.image.Image.setImageResourceReference(Image.java:178)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.image.Image.<init>(Image.java:101)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.image.Image.<init>(Image.java:77)
    at se.su.dsv.scipro.icons.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:83)
    at se.su.dsv.scipro.icons.ImageIcon.<init>(ImageIcon.java:93)
    at se.su.dsv.scipro.basepages.DemoPage.<init>(DemoPage.java:16)
    ... 32 more
```

I guess it is because the image file resides outside any Java package? How can I address this?

Comment: The org.apache.wicket.util.lang.Packages does not allow to traverse outside a java package as you try to do. (See the code in there) Resources in the webapps folder can be accessed without a ResourceReference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [`ContextRelativeResource`](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/resource/ContextRelativeResource.html). With it, the path to the image will be considered relative to the context root.

For instance, if you'd show this image with the following HTML:

```
<img src="images/icons/16/add.png">
```

Use the following:

```
new Image("add", new ContextRelativeResource("/images/icons/16/add.png")))
```

You might also find this [blog post](http://blog.armstrongconsulting.com/?p=91) useful.

There's no `ResourceReference` version of this variant that I'm aware of, although you can try to integrate the one attached in this JIRA issue: [WICKET-790](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-790)

Comment: Glad that solved your problem :-) If that icon is built and used in different situations throughout the application, it'll be recommendable to use a `ResourceReference`.